# java graphics - text color does not render correclty

Tags: java, graphics, awt

I want to add some white text to a dark background image and send that image for download. Here is my code:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("path\to\my\image.png"));
Font font = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18);
Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
g2d.setFont(font);
g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g2d.drawString("This is a test!", 20, 700);
//here is some codes for output result image
```

I have set text color to `white` as you can see, but weird problem is the generated text on image has other color than white!

This is part of my output image:

[image]

Can anyone help me to find out the problem?

Comment: I can not replicate the issue when viewing the modified saved image under another file name.

Comment: I do however get the particular text color you posted if I load in a `png` and save the modified image as `jpg`.

Comment: @DevilsHnd It pains me to see a clear, crisp image with something like text on it, saved as a JPEG. Either PNG ***or*** GIF is a better choice for that type of image data. OP: This is why it makes sense to post a [mre]. The problem is often not in the code snippet the questioner expects, and you cannot rely on someone as clever as DH popping in to help.